# What options exist for setting up a subnet limited proxy server for all network traffic to a remote client?

Tags: linux, ssh, internet, proxy, centos

I have a linux firewall / gateway (SME Server) and need to configure it to act as a proxy for a certain ip subnet and I'm not sure what server / daemons would work presently to meet my needs.  As noted it's an SME Server (contribs.org), but is essentially CentOS 5.7.

My use case is that I have a developer who needs to access some of my server resources from Europe, however some of the resources are not allowing access to the US servers.  Consequently I need to tunnel all Internet traffic through my own personal office connection so that a US IP is seen.  I figure the best way to accomplish this is via setting up a proxy that only allows his subnet so that I don't open a can of worms.

The other option is to just tunnel traffic through ssh, but perhaps would require some more configuration on his part.

I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.  What options exist presently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are looking for a proxy, unless you are looking to share http or related protocols on your intranet, even in that case it is a reverse proxy.

The problem you describe more sounds like a Virtual Private Network setup. The simplest way I met VPN like setup. The easiest way to do it from behind a firewall is with [Hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29) to my experience (this is a client to client end to end solution).

Otherwise you are looking to setup an IPSec implementation on the gateway such as [OpenSwan](https://www.openswan.org/projects/openswan/). It all depends on how wide access you need to provide to your local network.

If it is only a particular service on a single machine or a few it might be easiest to do [ssh tunneling](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) this can be done through the gateway machine as well.

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with ssh tunneling and vpn options.  Thanks.  There are no seemingly real simple solutions off the top.  It's not needed a lot and I don't need to give the user actual access to my local network, but it's about one in the same it seems in terms of the means to the end.